# jQuery 3D FlipBook Plugin not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I am trying to use the  jQuery 3D FlipBook Plugin (http://codecanyon.net/item/3d-flipbook-responsive-jquery-plugin/3946817) but it will not function.

I put the code on my php page (you can see here http://eurocom.servizieweb.it/pricelist/) but it does not work. Does anyone know why, or has anyone else had this problem?

I put the code. The problem is that not load on my page.

Thanks in advance.

```
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<script src="/catalogo/js/flipbook.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        jQuery("#container").flipBook({
            css:"/catalogo/css/black.css",
            pages:[
                {
                    src:"book/eng/page1.jpg",
                    thumb:"book/eng/thumb1.jpg",
                    title:"Cover",
                },
                {
                    src:"book/eng/page2.jpg",
                    thumb:"book/eng/thumb2.jpg",
                },
                {
                    src:"book/eng/page3.jpg",
                    thumb:"book/eng/thumb3.jpg",
                    title:"Studio Team",
                },
                {
                    src:"book/eng/page4.jpg",
                    thumb:"book/eng/thumb4.jpg"
                },
                {
                    src:"book/eng/page5.jpg",
                    thumb:"book/eng/thumb5.jpg",
                },
                {
                    src:"book/eng/page6.jpg",
                    thumb:"book/eng/thumb6.jpg",
                },
                {
                    src:"book/eng/page7.jpg",
                    thumb:"book/eng/thumb7.jpg"
                },
                {
                    src:"book/eng/page8.jpg",
                    thumb:"book/eng/thumb8.jpg",
                },
                {
                    src:"book/eng/page9.jpg",
                    thumb:"book/eng/thumb9.jpg"
                },
                {
                    src:"book/eng/page10.jpg",
                    thumb:"book/eng/thumb10.jpg"
                },
                {
                    src:"book/eng/page11.jpg",
                    thumb:"book/eng/thumb11.jpg"
                },
                {
                    src:"book/eng/page12.jpg",
                    thumb:"book/eng/thumb12.jpg"
                },
                {
                    src:"book/eng/page13.jpg",
                    thumb:"book/eng/thumb13.jpg"
                },
                {
                    src:"book/eng/page14.jpg",
                    thumb:"book/eng/thumb14.jpg"
                },
                {
                    src:"book/eng/page15.jpg",
                    thumb:"book/eng/thumb15.jpg",
                },
                {
                    src:"book/eng/page16.jpg",
                    thumb:"book/eng/thumb16.jpg"
                },
                {
                    src:"book/eng/page17.jpg",
                    thumb:"book/eng/thumb17.jpg"
                },
                {
                    src:"book/eng/page18.jpg",
                    thumb:"book/eng/thumb18.jpg"
                },
                {
                    src:"book/eng/page19.jpg",
                    thumb:"book/eng/thumb19.jpg"
                },
                {
                    src:"book/eng/page20.jpg",
                    thumb:"book/eng/thumb20.jpg"
                },
                {
                    src:"book/eng/page21.jpg",
                    thumb:"book/eng/thumb21.jpg"
                },
                {
                    src:"book/eng/page22.jpg",
                    thumb:"book/eng/thumb22.jpg"
                },
                {
                    src:"book/eng/page23.jpg",
                    thumb:"book/eng/thumb23.jpg",
                    title:"Accessries",
                },
                {
                    src:"book/eng/page24.jpg",
                    thumb:"book/eng/thumb24.jpg",
                },
                {
                    src:"book/eng/page25.jpg",
                    thumb:"book/eng/thumb25.jpg",
                },
                {
                    src:"book/eng/page26.jpg",
                    thumb:"book/eng/thumb26.jpg",
                    title:"Laboratory Team",
                },
                {
                    src:"book/eng/page27.jpg",
                    thumb:"book/eng/thumb27.jpg",
                },
                {
                    src:"book/eng/page28.jpg",
                    thumb:"book/eng/thumb28.jpg",
                },
                {
                    src:"book/eng/page29.jpg",
                    thumb:"book/eng/thumb29.jpg",
                },
                {
                    src:"book/eng/page30.jpg",
                    thumb:"book/eng/thumb30.jpg",
                },
                {
                    src:"book/eng/page31.jpg",
                    thumb:"book/eng/thumb31.jpg",
                },
                {
                    src:"book/eng/page32.jpg",
                    thumb:"book/eng/thumb32.jpg",
                },
                {
                    src:"book/eng/page33.jpg",
                    thumb:"book/eng/thumb33.jpg",
                },
                {
                    src:"book/eng/page34.jpg",
                    thumb:"book/eng/thumb34.jpg",
                },
                {
                    src:"book/eng/page35.jpg",
                    thumb:"book/eng/thumb35.jpg",
                },
                {
                    src:"book/eng/page36.jpg",
                    thumb:"book/eng/thumb36.jpg",
                },
                {
                    src:"book/eng/page37.jpg",
                    thumb:"book/eng/thumb37.jpg",
                },
                {
                    src:"book/eng/page38.jpg",
                    thumb:"book/eng/thumb38.jpg",
                    title:"Laboratory Team Accessories",
                },
                {
                    src:"book/eng/page39.jpg",
                    thumb:"book/eng/thumb39.jpg",
                },
                {
                    src:"book/eng/page40.jpg",
                    thumb:"book/eng/thumb40.jpg",
                },
                {
                    src:"book/eng/page41.jpg",
                    thumb:"book/eng/thumb41.jpg",
                },
                {
                    src:"book/eng/page42.jpg",
                    thumb:"book/eng/thumb42.jpg",
                },
            ]
        });
    })
</script>
```

Comment: Please post relevant code, and explain what part is not working.

Answer (score 0):

you have jquery js loaded twice

remove one of them, that might help your problem

Answer (score 0):

```
// 3D Flip Book Plugin not working   
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>3D FlipBook</title>
        
        <style type="text/css">
          body {
              margin: 0;
              padding: 0;
          }
          .flip-book-container{
            height: 100vh;
          }
        </style>
      </head>
      <body>
    
        <div class="flip-book-container" src="test.pdf">
    
        </div>
    
        <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    
        <script src="js/html2canvas.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/three.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/pdf.min.js"></script>
    
        <script src="src/3dflipbook.min.js"></script> 
    
      </body>
    </html>
```